# GridView inside VerticalViewPager Vertical Swiping

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-viewpager

I have custom VerticalViewPager in which is GridView which have vertical scrollbar, lets say it have 50 items...

Now, the problem is that I need to recognize when Gridview is scrolled on top and allow to viewpager top swipe and when gridview is scrolled on bottom then allow swipe to bottom...

This basically works out of the box, but the problem is that only when Im doing fast swipes over the gridview, then it allows me to go to another view... But when Im dragging by some other element which is for example over gridview, then it doesnt need to be fast to event for vertical viewpager be fired...
Is here anyone who will know?

By now I went to editing computeVerticalScrollRange() and overScrollBy() of gridview or setting overScrollMode, none of theese helped.

Im sorry if I dont understand exactly, what I am doing is I have class called ScrollableGridView where I implemented method which looks like:

**EDIT 1:**

```
@Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent){
        if(deltaY>0){
            System.out.println("Overscrolling to BOTTOM registered from ScrollableGridView");
        }else if(deltaY<0){
            System.out.println("Overscrolling to TOP registered from ScrollableGridView");
        }
        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, 0, isTouchEvent);
    }
```

there I can recognize if user is at the end or beginning on the list, I just cant figure out how I can say to the gridview stop pushing to top when user is on top, just let it on verticalviewpager, but allow user to go down in gridview and opposite when he is on end of gridview.

Methods I used like `super.setEnabled(false);` or `super.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);` blocks possibility to go backwards, it will block the gridview so VerticalViewpager will start working, but then scrolling back in gridview is disabled, which acts unnatural.

Comment: It should be same as two gridviews inside scrollview, you want to recognize when gridview is on beginning or end, to let parent(scrollview) do his thing, to scrol to another element-> to gridview above or below

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is basically the same thing the `SwipeToRefreshLayout` from Google does. It returns `true/false` during `onInterceptTouchEvent` depending on the resolution of the method `canChildScrollUp()` (which for your code you would do `canChildScrollVertically()`

here is the source code for the SwipeToRefreshLayout:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java

on line 613 you can see the `canChildScrollUp()` method which for API14+ just calls the `ViewCompat.canScrollVertically` or if below 14 checks `.getFirstVisiblePosition`.

the touch event interception should be simple too.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
   if(canChildScrollVertically()) return false;
   else return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for my slow response, I added the edit in my request, where I describe my problem better, Im afraid that I cant handle that user will not be able to scroll back when I use your solution, do you think it will still work correctly ?  And by inserting onInterceptTouchEvent, you mean to the GridView class? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I'm on holidays and only reading in the phone. I can't check carefully your update for the next week. The 'onInterceptTouchEvent' method is the one responsible on android to determine which ViewGroup will handle the touch event. This event is first dispatched by the system to the parent view and then to the child views. On your case you want the ViewPager to 'intercept' or not the touch event. Read about it on the documentation and do some testing. You'll get there

Comment: Thank you very much, I had same issue, thats why I asked, Im going to test it during week, only in case that I will be really unable to solve it by myself I will bother you, Im not hurry for the answer, Im very grateful for any help from your side! Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Okay, so later I found out that the guy from which I found code to make that vertical pager had setted wrongly variable inside onInterceptTouchEvent and it was taking swipe from too high diff, so I just changed that variable to small average to react to swipe. But thank you, it was helful at least to know where to look at :)